# SnapSVG: scale transform executing error-free but with no noticeable effect

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm quite new to both Snap & svg, trying to get savvy. I have an external SVG file that I'm loading as a fragment, then appending to a paper object. Then I want to scale the entire paper object.

The following code executes; the external file loads, the shadow is applied, it is visibly appended to the paper object. The transform, however, doesn't do anything. As far as I can tell, I've replicated the same essential effect as seen in [this tutorial](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6537-getting-started-with-snapsvg.html?start=1). Unfortunately, the official documentation, at least to me, is more or less useless due to it's ambiguity-via-concision appraoch. Anyone?

```
var logo
            $.ajax({
                url:"img/logo.svg",
                data: null,
                complete: function(resp) {
                    logo = Snap.parse(resp.responseText);
                    logo = logo.selectAll("g");
                    var logoPaper = Snap(app.sl.svg.splash.logo.svg).append(logo);
                    logoPaper.select("#logo-full-mask")
                             .attr({filter:logoPaper.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(0,0,5, "rgba(0,0,0,.3)"))})
                    var t = Snap.matrix().scale(1.4);
                    var trans = logoPaper.transform(t.toTransformString());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after a little fooling around I solved this on my own, but since it wasn't clear to me that this answer would be obvious to anyone who, like me, was new, I chose to post it.

I was trying to scale the paper object itself, which doesn't work (or else works in some unintended way that wasn't useful). Instead, elements of the object needed to be scaled; for my case, the easiest thing to do was create a group of all my paths and scale that, so:

```
var t = Snap.matrix().scale(1.4);
logoPaper.group(logoPaper.selectAll("path")).transform(t);
```

Comment: Yes, I don't think the SVG element itself is a transformable element. The other alternative would be to drop the paths into a group element and transform the group.

Comment: It will be transformable once UAs start to implement the upcoming SVG 2 spec. Firefox already has the SVG element as transformable because of this.